# Get latest two distinct location from table

Tags: mysql

Below is my table,

[image]

> SELECT DISTINCT(availability_location) as location FROM table_name WHERE user_id = '8' ORDER BY availability_date DESC LIMIT 2

I'm getting following result

[image]

I want following result :

> 2016-05-27  pune
>
> 2016-05-20  Burbank

i.e. Unique `availability_location` as well as latest two entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` for this:

```
SELECT availability_location as location,
       MAX(availability_date) AS max_date
FROM table_name 
WHERE user_id = '8' 
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY max_date DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Woking Fine I guess. 1st record is "2016-05-27" with "Pune" as location But in DB for "2016-05-27" date location is "pune"

Comment: look the case - "Pune" and "pune". I'm expecting "pune" as it's date is "2016-05-27" but getting "Pune"

Comment: @AP. This is because of the collation you are using: `Pune` and `pune` are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` and order by the max date :

```
 SELECT t.availability_location
 FROM table_name t 
 WHERE user_id = '8'
 GROUP BY t.availability_location 
 ORDER BY max(s.availability_date) DESC LIMIT 2
```

Output :

```
availability_location
---------------------
pune
Burbank
```

**EDIT:** next time, you should mention that you want it to be case sensitive. You can try doing it like this:

```
 SELECT t.availability_location 
 FROM table_name t 
 INNER JOIN(SELECT s.availability_location , max(s.availability_date) as max_d
            FROM table_name s
            WHERE s.user_id = '8'
            GROUP BY s.availability_location) t2
  ON(t2.availability_location = t.availability_location AND
     t2.max_d = t.availability_date)
 ORDER BY t.availability_date DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: This query give Pune and Burbank. I'm getting 1st record as  "2016-05-27" with "Pune" as location But in DB for "2016-05-27" date location is "pune"

Comment: I am talking about the second one, should be case sensitive @ap.